# Missing assembly reference in windows service solution

Tags: c#, windows

I have solution which consist two projects,one is class library and other one is windows service, i want to add reference of class library project to my windows service project.but when i added reference of class library project it is showing me assembly reference erro.I have also added dll to bin folder manually, but still it is showing me same error, can anyone give proper solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the exact error?

Comment: Are both project compiled for the same architecture? I means both x86/anyCPU...

Comment: Your question is tagged only with tag `c`, and you are talking about class library. I don't get it.

Comment: Sorry about the tag it is C#

Comment: Error 2 The type or namespace name 'BusinessLayer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\nilesh.kulkarni\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PdfFileWatcher\PdfFileWatcher\Service1.cs 17 7 PdfFileWatcher   I am getting this ERROR

Comment: And both projects are compiled in same architecture any CPU

Answer (score 0):

Are both the Class Library and the Windows Service targeting the same .NET framework versions?

If your class library is targeting a later version than the Windows Service, you can see this problem.